# Issue With Bootstrap Js Datepicker When Disabling Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

Hi guys I am having an issue with the datepicker which is found here:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/

Anyway the issue is that any dates which are 25 days or older break the disable dates from the 25th date onwards.

I have a jsfiddle demo which can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/robertg/p07udz76/1/

Here is the code which I am using:

```
var forbidden=['2015-03-05', '2015-03-20', '2015-03-24', '2015-03-27', '2015-03-30', '2015-04-04']

jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay:function(Date){
        var curr_date = Date.toJSON().substring(0,10);

        if (forbidden.indexOf(curr_date)>-1) return false;        
    },
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to get this sorted.

Thanks